# Normal distribution and the probabilities of type I errors

Tags: normal-distribution

New pupils entering a large secondary school take a general knowledge test during their first week. The mean score achieved on this test is 46.7 with a standard deviation of 14.3. At the beginning of the second term, pupils were asked if they would like to be considered for a team to represent the school in a general knowledge quiz. The test scores of a random sample of the pupils who did wish to be considered for the quiz team were:
38, 63, 79, 91, 42, 53, 84

a) Test, using the 5% significance level, whether the mean test score of those pupils who wished to be considered for the quiz team exceeded 46.7. Assume that the sample of scores is from a normal distribution with standard deviation 14.3. Interpret your conclusion in context:

My answer:

From sample, sample mean = 64.3

The sample mean is normally distributed by N(46.7, 14.3^2/7)

H0: μ = 46.7

H1: μ > 46.7

Φ^-1 (0.95) = 1.645 = z0.95 where Z is normally distributed by N(0,1)

z = (64.3 - 46.7)/(14.3/root(7)) = 3.256

3.256 > 1.645

Therefore, reject H0.

There is sufficient evidence at 5% level of significance that the mean test score has exceeded 46.7

b) A further random sample of those pupils who wished to be considered for the quiz team is to be taken and the test in part (a) repeated. State, with an explaination, the probability of making a Type I error in this test if the mean test score for all pupils who wished to be considered for the quiz team is:

i) 46.7

ii) 56.7

How do I do parts b) i) and ii)? Would it simply be 5%

Comment: (b) doesn't look answerable with the information given.  It's likely you're supposed to assume the variance of the new sample is either the variance of the sample from (a), which was $21^2,$ or the overall variance of $14.3^2,$ but the latter is not tenable (there already is evidence this is not the correct value to use) and the former relies on a relevant but highly uncertain estimate.  Most likely you are intended to keep using the $14.3$ value.

Comment: I managed to find the answers as according to the mark scheme... b) i) 0.05, H0 is true. Probability of making a Type 1 error is probability of rejecting i.e.
the significance level.  ii) 0, H0 is untrue ñ impossible to make a
Type 1 error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for showing your work for part (a).

Here is output from Minitab's z test procedure, which
matches your computations. You reject $H_0$ at the 5% level because $Z = 3.26 > 1.645,$ alternatively, because the P-value (0.001) is below 5%.

```
One-Sample Z 

Test of μ = 46.7 vs > 46.7
The assumed standard deviation = 14.3

N   Mean  SE Mean  95% Lower Bound     Z      P
7  64.30     5.40            55.41  3.26  0.001
```

(b) If you use 1.645 as the critical value, then the probability of Type I error is $P(\text{Reject}|\mu_0  = 46.7) = 0.05.$ So that's fine, when you have $\mu = 46.7,$ as in (i).

However, you may still have a little work to do for (ii). For a difference of 10 points above the null mean $\mu_0 = 46.7,$ Minitab's 'power and sample size' procedure for a one-sided z test gives the following power curve. Maybe this curve will help you judge whether you get a reasonable answer.

[image]

Recall that power against alternative $\mu_a = 56.7$ is defined as $P(\text{Rej}| \mu_a = 56.7).$

Comment: It's P(type I error) not P(type II error)

Comment: OK, right: Having trouble figuring what Type I error means in this context when you change $H_0.$  Maybe you're just supposed to say that for a right-sided z test, $\alpha = $ P(Type I Err) = 0.05, if you use critical value 1.645. That may make sense in a drill exercise. But not clear how it arises in an application.